# Display a popup every 3 pages

Tags: jquery, python, django

I'm using Django and I'm trying to display a pop up each time a user has seen 3 pages. I already have a solution but I would like to know if there is a best practice to do that.

Here is what I did :

In my views :

```
try :
    i = request.session.get('popup_index')
    request.session['popup_index'] = i+1
except :
    request.session['popup_index'] = 2

if i == 3:
    request.session['popup_index'] = 1
```

In my template :

html :

```
<input type='hidden' value='{{i}}' id='hidden_test'/>
```

js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#hidden_test').val() == 2){
        alert('TEST')
    }
});
```

Is that a good way to accomplish it ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Not to be rude, but does it work? Are you comfortable supporting it? If so, then it's a good way to accomplish it.

Comment: @Brandon Ok it's just that I am learning to code and I have no idea if there exists a usual way to accomplish that. I'll keep this solution then.

Comment: No worries. Questions that are primarily opinion-based aren't a good format for Stack Overflow. It's geared more toward solving specific problems with code, when you've exhausted all of your options and you're contemplating becoming a brick mason or smashing your keyboard into tiny bits :)